# Am trying to register but keep getting errors in my android application please what is the solution

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am not too good at android applications so most of the code are from the Youtube videos I watched while trying to learn how to code android application. I made some adjustment to what I want.

Here I am stuck trying to create a library management system. Every thing seems to be
working, except for the fact that I can't create a new user or sign in.

Code is running fine, but still do not understand the errors. From my Sign Activity there seems to be a misplacement of code, which I don't understand.

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextInputLayout editName;
    private TextInputLayout editEnrollNo;
    private TextInputLayout editCardNo;
    private TextInputLayout editPass1;
    private TextInputLayout editID;
    private TextInputLayout editPass;
    private Button buttonRegister;
    private TextView toSignIn;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private CheckBox check1;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private Spinner userType;
    private String type;
    private int type1;
    private int temp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        editID = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.editID);
        editPass = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.editPass);
        editPass1=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.editPass1);
        editName=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editEnrollNo=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.editEnrollNo);
        editCardNo=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.editCardNo);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        toSignIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toSignIn);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        check1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check1);
        userType=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.userType);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Select Account Type");
        list.add("User");
        list.add("Admin");

        ArrayAdapter adapter =new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        userType.setAdapter(adapter);
        userType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Select Account Type"))
                {
                    type=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    editPass1.setEnabled(false);
                    editPass.setEnabled(false);
                    editName.setEnabled(false);
                    editID.setEnabled(false);
                    editEnrollNo.setEnabled(false);
                    editCardNo.setEnabled(false);

                    editCardNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editEnrollNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editID.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editName.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editPass.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editPass1.setErrorEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("User"))
                {
                    type=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    editPass1.setEnabled(true);
                    editPass.setEnabled(true);
                    editName.setEnabled(true);
                    editID.setEnabled(true);
                    editEnrollNo.setEnabled(true);
                    editCardNo.setEnabled(true);

                    editCardNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editEnrollNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editID.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editName.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editPass.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editPass1.setErrorEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    type=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    editPass1.setEnabled(true);
                    editPass.setEnabled(true);
                    editName.setEnabled(true);
                    editID.setEnabled(true);
                    editEnrollNo.setEnabled(false);
                    editCardNo.setEnabled(false);

                    editCardNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editEnrollNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editID.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editName.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editPass.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    editPass1.setErrorEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        toSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        check1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private boolean verifyName()
    {

        String name=editName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if(name.isEmpty())
        {   editName.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editName.setError("Name Required");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            editName.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyCardNo()
    {
        String cardNo=editCardNo.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if(cardNo.isEmpty())
        {   editCardNo.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editCardNo.setError("Card No. Required");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            editCardNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyEnrollNo()
    {
        String enrollNo=editEnrollNo.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if(enrollNo.isEmpty())
        {   editEnrollNo.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editEnrollNo.setError("Enrollment No. Required");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            editEnrollNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyEmailId()
    {
        String emailId=editID.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if(emailId.isEmpty())
        {   editID.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editID.setError(" Email ID Required");
            return true;
        }
        else if(!emailId.endsWith("@iiitnr.edu.in"))
        {
            editID.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editID.setError(" Enter Valid Email ID");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            editID.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyPass()
    {
        String pass=editPass.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if(pass.isEmpty())
        {   editPass.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editPass.setError(" Password Required");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            editPass.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyPass1()
    {
        String pass1=editPass1.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String pass=editPass.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if(pass1.isEmpty())
        {   editPass1.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editPass1.setError("Confirm Password Required");
            return true;
        }
        else if(pass.equals(pass1))
        {
            editPass1.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            editPass1.setErrorEnabled(true);
            editPass1.setError("Passwords do not match");
            return true;
        }
    }

  private boolean verifyType()
    {
       if (type.equals("Select Account Type"))
       {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Please select account type !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

    private boolean verifyCard1()
    {
        db.collection("User").whereEqualTo("card",Integer.parseInt(editCardNo.getEditText().getText().toString().trim())).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                   temp=task.getResult().size();
                }
            }
        });
        if(temp==0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }

    private void registerUser()
    {
        if(verifyType())
           return;

        if(type.equals("User"))
        {
            boolean res= (verifyName()|verifyCardNo()|verifyEmailId()|verifyEnrollNo()|verifyPass()|verifyPass1());
            if(res==true)
                return;
        }
        if(type.equals("Admin"))
        {
            boolean res= (verifyName()|verifyEmailId()|verifyPass()|verifyPass1());
            if(res==true)
                return;
        }

        String id=editID.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String pass=editPass.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if(type.equals("User")){
            type1=0;
        }
        else
            type1=1;

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User ... ");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(id,pass).addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String id=editID.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                    String name=editName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                    if(type1==0)
                    {
                        int enroll=Integer.parseInt(editEnrollNo.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());
                        int card=Integer.parseInt(editCardNo.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());
                        db.collection("User").document(id).set(new User(name,id,enroll,card,type1)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                progressDialog.cancel();
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Registered Successfully !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignInActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Please Try Again !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {

                        db.collection("User").document(id).set(new Admin(type1,name,id)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                progressDialog.cancel();
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Registered Successfully !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignInActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Please Try Again !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

                else
                {   progressDialog.cancel();
                if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Already Registered ! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Registration Failed ! Try Again ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==check1)
        {
            if(check1.isChecked())
                buttonRegister.setEnabled(true);
            else
                buttonRegister.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if(v==buttonRegister)
            registerUser();

        else if(v==toSignIn) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Please can any one help?

Comment: Can you explain what error you are seeing and from where in your code?

Comment: The code is running but I can not register user. Keeps showing **registration failed try again later**

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: **W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:1475618): avc: denied { search } for name="battery" dev="sysfs" ino=6950 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c236,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:1475620): avc: denied { search } for name="battery" dev="sysfs" ino=6950** this is the error am getting

Answer (score 0):

When you return from a function, the code written after is never executed. In your method `registerUser()` every if condition that is true, returns. That means the actual code to register user is never reached.